# Spring MVC Controller: Redirect without parameters being added to my url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, restful-url

I'm trying to redirect without parameters being added to my URL.

```java
@Controller
...
public class SomeController
{
  ...
  @RequestMapping("save/")
  public String doSave(...)
  {
    ...
    return "redirect:/success/";
  }

  @RequestMapping("success/")
  public String doSuccess(...)
  {
    ...
    return "success";
  }
```

After a redirect my url looks always something like this: `.../success/?param1=xxx&param2=xxx`.
Since I want my URLs to be kind of RESTful and I never need the params after a redirect, I don't want them to be added on a redirect.

Any ideas how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Spring 3.1 use option [ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html#setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect%28boolean%29) to disable automatically adding model attributes to a redirect:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" />
```

Comment: is there an equialent for this on spring 3.0 ?

Comment: Assuming that rv is an instance of `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView`, one could set this per-RedirectView instance for more fine grained control: `rv.setExposeModelAttributes(<false or true>);`

Comment: For Spring >= 4.0 use ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true"

Comment: I think disabling it by default is a great idea.  You never know what kind of sensitive information you may have your model that you do not intend on making public.

Answer (score 34):

In Spring 3.1 a preferred way to control this behaviour is to add a [`RedirectAttributes`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) parameter to your method:

```
@RequestMapping("save/")
public String doSave(..., RedirectAttributes ra)
{
    ...
    return "redirect:/success/";
}
```

It disables addition of attributes by default and allows you to control which attributes to add explicitly.

In previous versions of Spring it was more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Since I have many redirects and find it anyoing to have to add unused RedirectAttributes-parameters to all my contoller-actions: It would be nice if there was a way to configure this 'behavior' in my Spring setup as default.

Answer (score 13):

Adding `RedirectAttributes` parameter doesn't work for me (may be because my HandlerInterceptorAdapter adds some stuff to model), but this approach does (thanks to @reallynic's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247239/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url#comment40067949_16841663)):

```
@RequestMapping("save/")
public View doSave(...)
{
    ...
    RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/success/");
    redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
    return redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Spring 4 there is a way to do this with java config, using annotations. I'm sharing it in case anyone needs it as I needed it.

On the config class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you need to add:

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
}
```

With this, you do not need to use `RedirectAttributes`, and it is an equivalent in java config to **Matroskin**'s answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Spring 3.1, you can use [Flash Scope](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html),
otherwise you can take a look at the method used in the most voted (not accepted) answer here:

[Spring MVC Controller redirect using URL parameters instead of in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500592/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-using-url-parameters-instead-of-in-response)

EDIT:

Nice article for 3.1 users:

http://www.tikalk.com/java/redirectattributes-new-feature-spring-mvc-31

Workaround for non-3.1 users:

[Spring MVC custom scope bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863472/spring-mvc-custom-scope-bean/5883270#5883270)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public ModelAndView getRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Locale locale, Model model) {

    ***model.asMap().clear();*** // This clear parameters in url

    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/test");

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.