# Spring 3.0 MVC :Redirect without parameters being added to my url

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to redirect without parameters being added to my url. I mean after a redirect, my url looks like this: .../success/?param1=xxx&param2=xxx.

This issue is exactly the same as this [Spring MVC Controller: Redirect without parameters being added to my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247239/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url)

The response https://stackoverflow.com/a/16841663/384984 is what I'm looking ([ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html#setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect%28boolean%29)). The problem is that I'm using Spring 3.0. How can I solve it with this Spring version?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. You can simply clear the `Model` map in your `Controller` method before redirect .

   ```
   model.asMap().clear();
   return "redirect:" + yourURL;
   ```
2. Don't expose the model attributes at all.

   ```
   RedirectView view = new RedirectView(yourURL, true);
   view.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
   return new ModelAndView(view);
   ```
3. Hope [this link](http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/common-reference-data-in-spring-mvc/) helps you in finding a better solution, specially point (4) `HandlerInterceptor` for common reference data within the entire web application

Comment: I believe you should not have that "redirect:" prefix in what you are passing to the RedirectView constructor; for obvious reason. :)