# How to hide springmvc redirect infomation in location bar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

In My Controller file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:/account/center";
        }
        return "public/login";
    }
```

After Then I login, and I input `/login` in the location bar, and redirect the `/account/center`.
But the url in the location bar show detail infomation.
eg:`http://localhost:8080/account/center?controllerName=com.xxx.test.HomeController&controllerAction=login&controllerPath=%2Flogin`.

How to hide `controllerName,controllerAction,controllerPath` in the redirect.

Comment: Use HTTP post parameters.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676206/spring-3-0-mvc-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247239/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url

Comment: Thank you!but can't useful.The parameter `controllerName,controllerAction,controllerPath` not I add, is springmvc  auto add.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get parameter through URL then you use HTTP Method as POST

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login() {
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:/account/center";
    }
    return "public/login";
}
```