# Spring automatic adds model param to url

Tags: java, spring

When I use `return redirect` in methods, spring automatically adds my Model variables like get params to url.
I've found solution here [Spring MVC Controller: Redirect without parameters being added to my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247239/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url)

but unfortunately it doesn't work with spring 3.2

Also i've found following

> When upgrading to spring-mvc-4.0.xsd, you should replace
>   enableMatrixVariables and ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect with
>   enable-matrix-variables and ignore-default-model-on-redirect
>   respectively.

but when i add this to my mvc-dispatcher.xml my IDE says that attribute is not allowed here.

Any solutions for **Spring 3.2?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried exactly? It seems that `ignore-default-model-on-redirect ` is actually what you should use.

Comment: In Spring 3.2, it actually seems that ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect is what should be used.

Comment: Hugo G. what that i got when i try to deploy application org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 71; columnNumber: 65; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java configuration add following to your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` child class:

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clear your model before the redirect :

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String doSomething(Model model, ...)
{
    // ....
    model.asMap().clear();
    return "redirect:list";
}
```

You can see other solutions here :

[Spring 3.0 MVC :Redirect without parameters being added to my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676206/spring-3-0-mvc-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url)

Comment: Sorry, I understood you did not want to pass your model attribute to the redirect URL. Can you be more specific about what you tried, what you get and what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Use this if you **do not** want your model data to be attached to the url parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("save/")
public View doSave(...)
{
    ...
    RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/success");
    redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
    return redirect;
}
```

Thanks to [reallynic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247239/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-without-parameters-being-added-to-my-url#comment40067949_16841663).