# what spring doc mean by all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI template variables in the redirect URL?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

what spring doc mean by :  all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI template variables in the redirect URL?
as i am new to spring if some one help me with example ... thanks advance

> what spring doc mean by all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI template variables in the redirect URL?

Answer (score 0):

That means if you have an attribute in your model, lets say

```
model.addAttribute("NewAttribute", "WhatsUp");
```

This attribute `newAttribute` will be appended to your URL, when you make a redirect.  Example:  `yourUrl.com?newAttribute=Whatsup`

If you wanted to pass a variable, but do not want it to show up in your URL as a parameter, then you use `addFlashAttribute` instead.

Example:

```
@GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectAttributes")
public RedirectView redirectWithRedirectAttributes(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
 
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("attributeWhichWillNotShowUpInURL", "redirectWithRedirectAttributes");

    attributes.addAttribute("attributeWhichWillShowUpInURL", "redirectWithRedirectAttributes");

    return new RedirectView("redirectedUrl");
}
```

According to the documentation, you could also simply choose to request that none of your Model attributes be appended to your URL, on redirect:

```
requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
```

> The RequestMappingHandlerAdapter provides a flag called
> "ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect" that can be used to indicate the
> content of the default Model should never be used if a controller
> method redirects

Good Read: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-redirect-attributes

Reference: [Spring automatic adds model param to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175340/spring-automatic-adds-model-param-to-url)

Comment: but this not the case in :
 Person p=new Person("name", "age");
    model.addAttribute("per", p);

Comment: Maybe clarify @javaway  Is the person json not appended to your url? or?

Comment: person not appended to the url

Comment: Kindly update your question with your code.  Expected results and what results you are getting now

Comment: model.addAttribute("NewAttribute", "WhatsUp"); NewAttribute will be appended to the URL 
but Person p=new Person("name", "age");
model.addAttribute(" person", "p"); p not appended to the URL

Comment: yes, it will be appended to the URL (as part of the URL String you see), If you want to know how to work with Plain Java Objects, in SpringMVC, please look at `@ModelAttribute`, otherwise, this may also give you hints https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-mvc%E2%80%99s

Comment: Full Code
    @PostMapping("/regist")
    public String regist(Person person, Model model) {
        Person p = new Person("name", "age");
        model.addAttribute("per", p);
        return "redirect:/info";
    }

    @GetMapping("/info")
    public String info() {
        return "result";
    }
per not appended to the URL