# How to call JSP from a java Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have a simple J2EE application with Spring.
Now I want from Java controller call another page. For example, I'm in registrazione.jsp, I click on one button, and I call a method in registrazioneController.java.

Now I want from registrazioneController.java, call another page, for example

home.jsp and I want pass any parameter in get.

It is possible?

this is the method that I use when I click the button

registrazioenControlle.java

```
public ModelAndView internalLoadPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Map model) throws Exception 
    {

        //to do
        //call another page for example home.html
        request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return new ModelAndView("home", model); 
    }
```

I'm try to use this code but no found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Controller redirect using URL parameters instead of in response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500592/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-using-url-parameters-instead-of-in-response)

Comment: You want to do redirect from controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500592/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-using-url-parameters-instead-of-in-response

Comment: you can always use reidrect in your controller

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided in the comments, you can also use RedirectAttributes, and *addAttribute* method if you want to append a parameter to URL upon redirect. This will also give you the *addFlashAttribute* that will store the attributes in the flash scope which will make it available to the redirected page. You can also return a simple string as the view name e.g. like

```
public String internalLoadPage(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception 
    {
      redirectAttributes.addAttribute("paramterKey", "parameter");
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("pageKey", "pageAttribute");
      return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

this assumes that the view suffix is configured in you view resolver configuration